# How to image changed and remains the same after mouseleave using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, hover

This is a dropdown menu, when hovered on  with an image on it it will be changed to the hovered version of the image and that is the current sitauation now, the problem or my question is when the mouse is hovered on the submenus of  the image in  will be back to it's original image which is not the hovered image version, I wanted it to remain the hovered image while hovering on it's submenus.

here are the codes if this could help you understand.

```js
jQuery(function($){ 
    $('.main-menu > li').on('mouseover', function(){
  /*$(this).find('.sub-menus').css('display', 'block');*/       
  $(this).find('.sub-menus').show();
        /*$(this).children('a').addClass('on');*/
 });
    $('.main-menu > li').on('mouseleave', function(){
  /*$(this).find('.sub-menus').css('display', 'none');*/
  $(this).find('.sub-menus').hide();
        /*$(this).children('a').removeClass('on');*/
 });
    
    $('.main-menu > li').find('a').hover(function() {
        var target = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        var newTarg = target.replace('.png', '_hover.png');
        $(this).find('img').attr("src", newTarg);
    }, function() {
        var target = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        var newTarg = target.replace('_hover.png', '.png');
        $(this).find('img').attr("src", newTarg);
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="mid-header">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul class="main-menu">
            <li class="item-menu01">
                <a href="#" class="item-menu-text01"><img src="../images/tit/tit_main_menu01.png"/></a>
                <div class="sub-menus">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                       <div class="left-curve">
                            <ul class="sub-menu-items right-curve">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" class="item-submenu01-01">
                                        <img src="../images/tit/tit_submenu_01_01.png"/>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" class="item-submenu01-02">
                                        <img src="../images/tit/tit_submenu_01_02.png"/>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" class="item-submenu01-03">
                                        <img src="../images/tit/tit_submenu_01_03.png"/>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="last-child">
                                    <a href="#" class="item-submenu01-04">
                                        <img src="../images/tit/tit_submenu_01_04.png"/>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item-menu02">
                <a href="#" class="item-menu-text02"><img src="../images/tit/tit_main_menu02.png"/></a>
                <div class="sub-menus">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="left-curve">
                            <ul class="sub-menu-items right-curve">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" class="item-submenu02-01">
                                        <img src="../images/tit/tit_submenu_02_01.png"/>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" class="item-submenu02-02">
                                        <img src="../images/tit/tit_submenu_02_02.png"/>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" class="item-submenu02-03">
                                        <img src="../images/tit/tit_submenu_02_03.png"/>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" class="item-submenu02-04">
                                        <img src="../images/tit/tit_submenu_02_04.png"/>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" class="item-submenu02-05">
                                        <img src="../images/tit/tit_submenu_02_05.png"/>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#" class="item-submenu02-06">
                                        <img src="../images/tit/tit_submenu_02_06.png"/>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="last-child">
                                    <a href="#" class="item-submenu02-07">
                                        <img src="../images/tit/tit_submenu_02_07.png"/>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is for the image hover, you are targeting the anchor element so when you move to the sub menu, the mouseleave event of the anchor element will fire and the hovered image will be replaced with the default one.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.main-menu > li').hover(function () {
        /*$(this).find('.sub-menus').css('display', 'block');*/
        $(this).find('.sub-menus').show();
        /*$(this).children('a').addClass('on');*/
    }, function () {
        /*$(this).find('.sub-menus').css('display', 'none');*/
        $(this).find('.sub-menus').hide();
        /*$(this).children('a').removeClass('on');*/
    });

    $('.main-menu li').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('> a > img').attr('src', function (i, src) {
            return src.replace('.png', '_hover.png');
        })
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('> a > img').attr('src', function (i, src) {
            return src.replace('_hover.png', '.png');
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: This is good, It worked. But now the hover of my sub-menus is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Try Including One more class to your Jquery  :

```
$('.main-menu > li, .main-menu > li > li').on('mouseover', function(){

}
```